# nmake: Is there a built-in macro for current working directory?

Tags: makefile, nmake

I need the current working directory from nmake for the directory it is currently building in to be used in a makefile.
Is there some kind of built-in macro for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms933742.aspx),

```
MAKEDIR     Current directory when Nmake.exe was invoked.
```

may be what you want.

Comment: That could be it. The description makes it sound like it's just the directory from which the user ran nmake which isn't what I want but the docs say it's recursive so it may be right. I'll have to try it and see.